# SQL Server: Post Insert Pre Commit Trigger

Tags: sql-server, database, triggers

I have been looking up this for a bit now and i cannot find any way to fire a trigger after an insert has taken place but before the commit takes place. I need to do this so that I have the ability to role back if there is something wrong with the information inserted but also need to check the information inserted so it needs to be after the inserting is complete.

Is there a trigger to do this or any methods that can reproduce this same functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The triggers are activated before the commit takes place. Within a trigger you could use `ROLLBACK` if some checks fails:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Product(
    Id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Name NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    UnitPrice NUMERIC(9,2) NOT NULL -- CHECK (UnitPrice > 0)
);
GO
CREATE TRIGGER trgIU_Product_VerifyUnitPrice
ON dbo.Product
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    IF UPDATE(UnitPrice)
    BEGIN
        -- For simple checks you could use CHECK constraints
        -- inserted and deleted are virtual tables store the new and the old rows (values)
        IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM inserted WHERE UnitPrice <= 0)
        BEGIN
            ROLLBACK; -- It "cancels" current transaction
            RAISERROR('Wrong UnitPrice.',16,1); -- It notifies the caller that there is an error
        END
    END
END;
GO

SET NOCOUNT ON;
PRINT 'Test #1';
INSERT INTO dbo.Product (Id,Name,UnitPrice)
SELECT  1 , 'PCs      ', 1200;

PRINT 'Test #2';
INSERT INTO dbo.Product (Id,Name,UnitPrice)
SELECT  2 , 'MACs     ', 2200;

PRINT 'Test #3';
INSERT INTO dbo.Product (Id,Name,UnitPrice)
SELECT  3 , 'Keyboard ', 0;

PRINT 'Test #4';
INSERT INTO dbo.Product (Id,Name,UnitPrice)
SELECT  4 , 'AAA', 111
UNION ALL
SELECT  5 , 'BBB', 0;
GO

PRINT 'Test #5';
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO dbo.Product (Id,Name,UnitPrice)
SELECT  6 , 'CCC', 222
UNION ALL
SELECT  7 , 'DDD', 0;
COMMIT TRANSACTION;
GO
SELECT @@TRANCOUNT AS [Active transactions count];
GO

PRINT 'Test #6';
SELECT * FROM dbo.Product;
```

Results:

```
/*
Test #1

Test #2

Test #3
Msg 50000, Level 16, State 1, Procedure trgIU_Product_VerifyUnitPrice, Line 11
Wrong UnitPrice.
Msg 3609, Level 16, State 1, Line 11
The transaction ended in the trigger. The batch has been aborted.

Test #4
Msg 50000, Level 16, State 1, Procedure trgIU_Product_VerifyUnitPrice, Line 11
Wrong UnitPrice.
Msg 3609, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
The transaction ended in the trigger. The batch has been aborted.

Test #5
Msg 50000, Level 16, State 1, Procedure trgIU_Product_VerifyUnitPrice, Line 11
Wrong UnitPrice.
Msg 3609, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
The transaction ended in the trigger. The batch has been aborted.
Active transactions count
-------------------------
0

Test #6
Id Name UnitPrice
-- ---- ---------
1  PCs  1200.00
2  MACs 2200.00
*/
```

References: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx

Answer (score 1):

See what [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx) says about AFTER TRIGGER.

> AFTER specifies that the DML trigger is fired only when all operations
>   specified in the triggering SQL statement have executed successfully.

You can easily write an AFTER trigger, but you cannot use it to control what happens just before transaction gets committed. There may be an explicit transaction which stays open until e.g. 'manually' rolled back or committed.